# How do I get Spring-Boot devtools to live reload updated static files when using VSCode and Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-devtools

I've been attempting to get Spring Boot's devtools to work in VSCode on a new project utilizing Gradle as it's builder. However, for some reason whenever a change is made to the `src\main\resources\static\index.html` it does not automatically live reload the changes and doesn't rebuild the file at `build\resources\main\static\index.html`. Manually changing this file and refreshing the browser does load the new changes.

When creating the same project utilizing **Maven** as the builder devtools does work as intended, showing the new changes upon browser refresh.

I am using:

- Java: 17.0.8.1
- Gradle 8.4
- vscode 1.84.2
- spring-boot-starter-web 3.1.5
- spring-boot-devtools 3.1.5

I've tried modifying the application.yaml file to watch an additional path of the resources static folder.